# How to get to PowerPivot data within VBA?

Tags: excel, powerpivot, vba

I have my data imported to PowerPivot (based on sql query) table in my workbook. I need to copy this data to the worksheet to do some modifications. How to accomplish it with VBA?

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct API but a workaround is to copy the data into the worksheet and format the data as table then create a "Linked Table" to import the data. The databases PP accesses do have APIs to access them directly from within Excel though.

Microsoft Office provides drivers that you can use to retrieve data from the following data sources:

Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services (OLAP provider)
Microsoft Office Access
dBASE
Microsoft FoxPro
Microsoft Office Excel
Oracle
Paradox
Text file databases

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/use-microsoft-query-to-retrieve-external-data-HA010099664.aspx